# Printing the value of a pointer in C

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
int *i,*j;

printf("%u",i);
}
```

The above program will result in output as 0

```
int main()
{

int *i,*j;

j=i;
printf("%u",i);
}
```

but

The above program will result in non zero. Why?

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour. Your program could print the entire work of Shakespeare or paint your ceiling yellow.

Answer (score 5):

Both pointers are not initialized so their initial value is indeterminate. Accessing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

Moreover use `p` conversion specifier to print a pointer value (and yes the cast is also required) as `u` requires an `unsigned int` argument :

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the pointer to an actual integer memory location and then print the value of the address and the data being pointed at.

```
main() {
    int q = 0, *p = &q;
    printf("%p %d", p, *p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier for a pointer is `%p`. Using another specifier results in Undefined Behavior; whether the output is `0` or not is undefined.

For a complete list of format specifiers, click [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).